# facebook "like box" for page

Tags: iframe, facebook-likebox

I set up my website's facebook account as a Page on my facebook account (this was probably incorrect, but I didn't know better at the time). I have switched my account to Use Facebook as a Page. I am trying to create a like box with avatars for my website (www.zealforadeal.com).  I get the error code: *To access this page, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as your page to using Facebook as yourself.*  How can I create a Like Box for my page (http://www.facebook.com/zealforadeal) ?

(I never use my facebook account for anything other than the Page)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about the purpose of the 'Like box'. The 'like box' shows the people who have 'Liked' your Facebook page,and your Facebook page status updates.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the [like box page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) and paste your url (http://www.facebook.com/zealforadeal) into Facebook Page URL field.

Comment: I did that, and it works as long as I use Facebook as myself.  But when I switch to using Facebook as my page, my Like Box is empty on my website, and I get the error code above on facebook developers. (I want to use Facebook as my Page). Also, when I write on someone's wall while using Facebook as my Page, all is well.  But when I switch back to using Facebook as myself (so my Like Box will work), the entry I wrote on that person's wall disappears.  It reappears when I switch back to using Facebook as my Page.